# Why should Map implementations override foreach?

Tags: performance, algorithm, scala, dictionary

The [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map) for `scala.collection.mutable.Map` says.

> It is also good idea to override methods `foreach` and `size` for efficiency.

Overriding `size` is (possibly) a `O(n)` to `O(1)` improvement.

But what is the value of overriding `foreach`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default implementation of foreach in scala.collection.immutable.MapLike uses the iterator to implement foreach. This implementation is inherited from [IterableLike](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L1).

```
def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit =
  iterator.foreach(f)
```

But implementing an iterator is usually much more complex than implementing foreach. An iterator has to explicitly keep track of the current position, which requires state and can require substantial logic in case of a tree-like structure like e.g. what is used for immutable HashMaps. Here is the iterator for immutable HashMaps and HashSets from the current collections library as an example [TrieIterator](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/TrieIterator.scala). Not exactly simple, right?

A foreach method on the other hand uses the call stack to track the current position, and is therefore very simple and efficient to implement. A foreach method for a binary tree is just left.foreach(f); right.foreach(f).

So depending on how complex the iterator for your map is, it might indeed be a good idea to implement foreach separately for performance.

Comment: Interestingly, though, the documentation for [`immutable.Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map) has no such advice.

Comment: Perhaps they don't expect as many people to extend immutable.Map? Overriding foreach for performance is certainly a good idea for immutable maps as well, and HashMap obviously does it.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it's because you are dealing with a mutable Map. If you have many iterations over a mutable collection that is shared between several processes, things can go very very wrong. For instance, if elements are deleted but not traversed in an iterator, what then? The default implementation of the `foreach` method (from [Iterator](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L727)) does not use any kind of concurrency handling.

The same comments does not appear in the immutable version.

Comment: `Map` does guarantee anything about thread-safeness. Generally in Java/Scala, things are not thread-safe unless declared otherwise, so as to not incur synchronization penalties.